# Routes Problem with node.js 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios, router

I tried creating a user authentication with MERN stack, the authentication also has a verification link so user have to verify before logging in, but the mail is sent to user successfully but, the link is throwing error "**404 not found**" I'll provide the code below:

```
**App.js**
import './App.css';
import Tracking from './Page/Tracking';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Page/Login';
import SignUp from './Page/SignUp';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import AirlinesList from './Page/AirlinesList';
import EmailVerify from './verify';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Tracking />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path="/airline-list" element={<AirlinesList />} />
        <Route path="/users/:id/verify/:token" element={<EmailVerify />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
**Backend server.js**
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { UserModel, MyModel, TrackedAwbModel } = require('./modules/schema');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv/config')
const Token = require('./modules/token')
const sendEmail = require('./sendEmail')
const crypto = require('crypto');

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
    });
    response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(400);
app.use(express.json())

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB', err);
});

app.get('/data', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await MyModel.find();
        res.json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

app.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    const { name, designation, email, companyName, mobileno, password } = req.body;
    try {
        const existingUser = await UserModel.findOne({ email: email });
        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Email or username already exists" });
        }

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        const newUser = await UserModel.create({ name, designation, email, companyName, mobileno, password: hashedPassword });
        user = await new UserModel({ ...req.body, password: hashedPassword }).save();

        const token = await new Token({
            userId: user._id,
            token: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex")
        }).save();

        const url = `http://localhost:3000/users/${user._id}/verify/${token.token}`;
        await sendEmail(user.email, "Verify Air Track", url);

        res.json({ message: "User created successfully, Verify your email", userId: newUser._id });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
})

app.get("/:id/verify/:token", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
        if (!user) return res.status(400).send({ message: "Invalid link" });

        const token = await Token.findOne({
            userId: user._id,
            token: req.params.token
        });
        if (!token) return res.status(400).send({ message: "Invalid link" });

        await UserModel.updateOne({ _id: user._id, isEmailVerified: true })
        await token.remove()

        res.status(200).send({ message: "Email Verified Succesfully" })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
})

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (!passwordMatch) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid password" });
        }

        if (!user.isEmailVerified) {
            let token = await Token.findOne({ userId: user._id });
            if (!token) {
                token = await new Token({
                    userId: user._id,
                    token: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex")
                }).save();
                const url = `${process.env.BASE_URL}users/${userd._id}/verify/${token.token}`
                await sendEmail(user.email, "Verify Air Track", url);
            }
            return res.status(401).json({ error: "Email not verified" })
        }

        res.json({ message: "Login successful", user });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 4000
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
})
```

```
**SendEmail.js**
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
require('dotenv/config')

module.exports = async (email, subject, text) => {
    try {
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
            port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
            secure: false,
            auth: {
                user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
                pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
            }
        });

        await transporter.sendMail({
            from: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
            to: email,
            subject: subject,
            text: text
        })
        console.log("Email sent succesfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Email not sent");
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

```
**SignUp page** 
import React, { useState } from "react"
import "./Styles/Login.css"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

function SignUp() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: "",
        designation: "",
        companyName: "",
        email: "",
        mobileno: "",
        password: "",
        otp: ""
    });
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("");
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");
    const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (isSubmitting) {
            return;
        }

        setIsSubmitting(true);

        axios.post("http://localhost:4000/users", formData)
            .then(response => {
                setFormData({
                    name: "",
                    designation: "",
                    companyName: "",
                    email: "",
                    mobileno: "",
                    password: "",
                });
                setError("");
                setMsg(response.msg)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response) {
                    if (error.response.status === 400) {
                        toast.error("Email or username already exists");
                    } else {
                        toast.error("An error occurred. Please try again later.");
                    }
                } else {
                    toast.error("Network error. Please check your internet conneciton");
                }
            }).finally(() => {
                setIsSubmitting(false);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className="login">
            <h1 className="log-head" style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>Sign up</h1>
            <div>
                <form className="log-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <span className="input-row">
                        <div className="user-input">
                            <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" name="name" id="name" required
                                value={formData.name}
                                onChange={handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="user-input">
                            <label htmlFor="designaiton">Designation:</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter designation" name="designation" id="designation" required
                                value={formData.designation}
                                onChange={handleChange} />
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span className="input-row">
                        <div className="user-input">
                            <label htmlFor="company-name">Company Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter company name" name="companyName" id="company-name" required
                                value={formData.companyName}
                                onChange={handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="user-input">
                            <label htmlFor="input">Company Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter company email" name="email" id="input" required
                                value={formData.email}
                                onChange={handleChange} />
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span className="input-row">
                        <div className="user-input">
                            <label htmlFor="username">Mobile no:</label>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter mobile-no" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" required
                                value={formData.mobileno}
                                onChange={handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="user-input">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" id="password" required
                                value={formData.password}
                                onChange={handleChange} />
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <div >
                        <input type="checkbox" id="horns" name="horns" required />
                        <label htmlFor="horns">I agree to terms and conditions</label>
                    </div>

                    {error && <p className="error-message">{error}</p>}
                    {msg && <p className="success-message">{msg}</p>}
                    <p className="sign-para">Already a user? <Link to='/login'>Log In</Link></p>
                    <button className="login-btn" type="submit">
                        Sign up
                    </button>

                </form>
            </div >
            <ToastContainer />
        </div >

    )
};
export default SignUp;
```

I params and changed to `const [id, token] = UseParams()` it gives me AxiosError.